# Django form validation with foreign keys from two different tables

Tags: django

I have a question with forms validation for Django that I suspect is trivial but I am not Getting what I am missing as I am diving in django without too much understanding of some fundamental aspects and a bit confused by the documentation or issue here.

This is not my code but a simplified version of the core problem:

So my model would be something like:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
    name  = models.TextField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, unique=True)
        clothing= models.ManyToManyField(Clothing, through='childs')

class Clothing(models.Model):   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
    name  = models.TextField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    
class Childs(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('amount',)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, db_column='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clothing = models.ForeignKey(Clothing,  db_column='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    

class FamilyDressing(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Childs
        fields = ('parent', 'clothing', 'amount')
```

which hopefully is right.

Lets imagine a way of uploading a csv file with a list of children, their associated parent and associated piece of cloth.

To validate such form I thought I first can validate the Clothing model, that seems to work, then validate the childs model with the parent name, piece of cloth and amount but somehow I can only validate parent and amount together but not the three fields at once where it is giving me

{"message": "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.", "code": "invalid_choice"}

the data passed would be something like :

```
data= {'parent': 'Lisa', 'clothing': 'dress', 'amount': 2}
```

I was expecting to be able to validate the form.

Edit:

Actually I am now noticing that there is a connected errors which make me rethink the whole issue and thinking it is not possible anyway.

If I dont define a custom for primary key, I know I am going to run into this annoying error `operator does not exist: bigint = text` 
when django is gonna try to compare the childs id with ingredient name

I guess I would need to define a primary key for Childs as well but then that means I would need the CSV upload sheet to contain the name of the childs and I kind of wanted to leave it nameless for practicality or name it the same as the parent name if it was possible.